# Возврат списка из lambda

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Друзья, подскажите, почему я получаю NONE?
И как этого избежать?

```
cons = lambda x, y: y.append(x)
print(cons(1, [0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `append` ничего и не возвращает. Можно сделать так:

```py
# складываем списки и возвращаем
cons = lambda x, y: y + [x]
print(cons(1, [0]))
```

Или так:

```py
# возвращаем список после использования append, потом выкидываем лишнее
cons = lambda x, y: (y.append(x), y)
print(cons(1, [0])[1])
```

Вывод будет одинаковый:

```
[0, 1]
```